# Filter with multiple values

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have items which should have multiple (e.g. categories). Now I want to filter my items to these categories.
I think the task is not possible with the filter-directive without using a custom filter, right?

I came up with a solution, but it looks dirty and wrong to me:

```
$scope.filterList = function (item) {
    var found = false;
    var allFalse = true;
    angular.forEach(item.attributes, function (value, key) {
        if ($scope.activeAttributes[value.name] === true) {
            found = true;
        }
    });
    angular.forEach($scope.activeAttributes, function (value, key) {
        if (value === true) {
            allFalse = false;
        }
    });
    $log.log("length: " + Object.keys($scope.activeAttributes).length);
    if (found === true || Object.keys($scope.activeAttributes).length === 0 || allFalse === true) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

[Demo JSFiddle of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/bonzai86/yzdxrtou/5/)

I thought with Angular, that the code should be simple and most of the work should be done by Angular. What if I need to filter more attributes?